# парсинг новости из сайта . выдает ошибку (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, jsoup

```
  package com.company;

 import  org.jsoup.Jsoup;
 import  org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
   import  org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import  org.jsoup.select.Elements;

  import java.io.IOException;

    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc=null;
    try{
        doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.psu.ru/news").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("нет интернета");
    }
    Elements spans=doc.select("div [class=item__title]");
    Element span=spans.get(0);
    System.out.println(span.text());
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень вероятно, что эта строчка `Element span=spans.get(0);` выбрасывает исключение. Просто добавьте проверку того, что Elements не пусто и создержит элемент №0, который вы вытаскиваете.